# Python Dictionary access internal value in declaration stage

Tags: python, python-2.7

working in python 2.7, I was wondering if there is a way to accomplish the following :

```
obj = {

  "a" : True,
  "b" : 1 if "a" else 200

}
```

I was wondering if there was any way to get "a" value or if it is impossible as obj is not yet defined.

Thanks

Edit :

```
TaskOfJobs = []
JobsHandler = [ {...} , ... ]

for j in JobsHandler :

    TaskOfJobs.append({
        "Completed"   : (expression to verify if is completed),
        "CompletedOn" : date.now() if "Completed" else None
    })
```

Guys, thanks for your time.
Of course I can accomplish this in many ways, for example declaring a variable with the expression result before the obj creation, then use that variable inside.

As I'm starting to learn python, I wan just wandering if something like that was possible or not.

Thanks

Comment: FYI, `if "a"` is always **true**.

Comment: what is the reason you want to do this? Try to give some context

Comment: Can you provide an example closer to your use case? I assume you are trying to dynamically build a dictionary and do not know the value of `obj["a"]` beforehand

Comment: @Austin ok, thats no what I care about, I want understand how to resolve that expression in photon

Comment: Yes but your expression right now doesn't make any sense. Try to provide a [mre] closest to your use-case

Comment: @Tomerikoo hope my edit could explain better what I was wondering

Comment: According to your edit, I guess you can just do `date.now() if (expression to verify if is completed) else None` or simply don't do it in one expression. What's wrong with checking `if task_completed:` and initializing the dict accordingly...

Comment: @Tomerikoo there is nothing wrong with checking it before the obj initialization. Mine was only curiosity

Comment: So bottom line is, you have to remember that you can't access a dict until it is actually created. While there are a few ways of going around it, directly accessing a key during initialization is not possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the definition of `a` to the outer scope and access it inside the `dictionary`:

```py
a = True
obj = {
  "a" : a,
  "b" : 1 if a else 200
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're doing this because `a` is always `true`
but this code will work

```py
obj = {
  "a" : True
}

if(obj['a']):
 obj['b'] = 1
else :
 obj['b'] = 200
```

Comment: My question was simply if it is possible to access an internal value inside a dictionary declaration.